# using a byobu and disconnected session how to see message on screen

Tags: 11.10, screen, byobu

I use byobu on sh and was doing some program which was left over for  at least 24 hours,
I had disconnected from the machine and logged in back after 24 hours is there a way I could see the messages which were on screen in this case.I am using Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run

```
byobu
```

again and it will re-attach to the current session in the background (for the current user). If there is no, it will create a new session.

In case a lot of output has been produced and you'd like to scroll up, use the *Copy mode* by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>. It will "disconnect" the cursor and allows you to scroll up and *search*. Use the arrow keys (<kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd>) or <kbd>PageUp</kbd> / <kbd>PageDown</kbd> keys to move around, and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get control back on the shell.

See also: [Can Mouse Wheel Scrolling be enabled in Byobu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199290/can-mouse-wheel-scrolling-be-enabled-in-byobu)?

Comment: yes I did the same it attached the same session but the problem is there are a lot of messages on screen and the scroll bar has its limit

Comment: Use F7 to enable copy mode and you can scroll using arrow keys or page-up/down.

Comment: I logged on to the system remotley via ssh and currently using putty from Windows so F7 pressed here how will it get there?

Comment: You're diverging from your original question. If pressing F7 doesn't propagate through PuTTY to byobu, then it's Windows/PuTTY issue, much wider than just byobu or getting messages on the screen.

Comment: ok if I press F7 to enable copy mode then how to disable it and does it record in any file all the output?

Comment: I just read man of byobu my wireless card needs F2 function and I see in byobu F2 to create new window etc if I press F2 to create a new window in byobu my wireless (and in turn the  ssh ) gets disconnected is there a way out in this situation

Comment: 1) re-read my answer, 2) other question, 3) other question. hint: byobu has **nothing to do with wireless**.

Comment: @gertvdijk he has those function keys mapped to actions. there should be an option to disable them in bios, or he might have to try holding fn key and pressing function keys. he has a valid point, probably not phrased clearly.